# How to assign a unique color to a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to change the colors of stacked bar charts in GGplot2. I want the top bar to be 'grey' for every 'possession_abbr' and I want the bottom color to be unique for all 'possession_abbr'. I already have a column in my data called 'team_color' that contains a unique color for all  'possession_abbr'. How would I fill every bottom bar with each unique color?

Here is what I have tried:

```
stack <- ggplot(d, aes(x=possession_abbr, y=count, fill=run_pass ) )+
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", d$team_color) ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "Proportion of Pass and Run Plays for Each Team", 
       subtitle = "(2022 Season)", x= "", y= "Proportion of Plays",
       fill = "Run or Pass")
```

And here is the resulting plot:
[image]

My code seems to fill the bottom bar with the first color found in d$team_color. How would I get each unique color for every team?

I have been stuck for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share 5 rows of sample data? `dput(d[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows (select only the needed columns if you have a bunch!)

Answer (score 1):

Mapping a variabler with two categories on fill will give you two colors. That's it. Instead, map the interaction of `possession_abbr` and `run_pass` on the `fill` aes. Second, create a color palette with your team colors and the same amount of `grey`. Third, name this color palette according to the team names or more correctly according to the interaction of `possession_abbr` and `run_pass`. Finally, for the legend I show only the first grey and the first colored category for which I use the `breaks` argument.

Using some fake random example data:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
  possession_abbr = LETTERS,
  run_pass = rep(c("run", "pass"), each = 26),
  count = runif(26 * 2)
)
d <- transform(d, fill = paste(possession_abbr, run_pass, sep = "."))

# Team colors
team_color <- scales::hue_pal()(26)
# Team names
team_names <- unique(d$possession_abbr)

# Color palette
pal_color <- c(team_color, rep("grey", 26))
# Name the color palette
names(pal_color) <- c(
  paste(team_names, "run", sep = "."),
  paste(team_names, "pass", sep = ".")
)

ggplot(d, aes(x = possession_abbr, y = count, group = run_pass, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_color, breaks = c("A.pass", "A.run"), labels = c("pass", "run")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(
    title = "Proportion of Pass and Run Plays for Each Team",
    subtitle = "(2022 Season)", x = "", y = "Proportion of Plays",
    fill = "Run or Pass"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]